# MySQL Create Trigger For Select Columns

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table with many columns, 20+. I want to set a trigger on an Update On but I would not like it to occur if 4 of the columns are updated.

ie:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER triggerName
AFTER UPDATE ON tableName FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF ((NEW.columnA <> OLD.columnA)||(NEW.columnB <> OLD.columnB)[...]||(NEW.columnV <> OLD.columnV)) THEN
        SET NEW.columnX = 'someValue', NEW.columnY = 'someOtherValue'
  END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Is there a simpler/ more elegant solution to this rather than including every column except the 4 that I'd like to ignore in the IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  But, to make your life more complicated, be careful about `NULL` values.  Perhaps it should look more like:

```
if ((NEW.ColumnA <> OLD.ColumnA AND NOT (NEW.ColumnA IS NULL and OLD.ColumnA IS NULL)) OR
    . . .
   )
```

Comment: thanks, that worked but now I have to performance tune since there are so many columns